# Visual Studio App Center: crashes and errors not logged on Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center, crashlytics-android

We have implemented Visual Studio App Center crashes and errors for our project. Last 40days App Center crashes and errors logged. Now we have changed the version number in android for the next release But solution crashes and errors not logging in appcenter. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: contact AppCenter support

Comment: Have you uploaded the new version of the app to AppCenter?